# Escaping special characters in URL such as '+' in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, url, web

I have an issue submitting forms when the entry contains a special character such as a '+', as this is marked as a special character in URLS (since spaces cant appear in URLS).  This means that when submitting data, this is converted to a space which means incorrect data can get stored in the database.

Is there a way to get around this using escape sequences in ASP.NET? I am using Linq for database manipulation if that helps with identifying a solution.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: use form `method="POST"` to post your form instead of using `GET` which will use the url & querystring.